Export tikz images to odt file on Windows: trouble with pdf2svg
I would need to convert my .tex file into an editable format such as odt. After various vicissitudes, I managed to find the right way. The equations are exported almost correctly (the command (\sin is transcribed as s), but there is no trace of the images created with tikz.
The problem is that the script does not recognize the pdf2svg command, since it is not installed. I followed the instructions, but being in a Windows environment, commands like ./configure --prefix=/usr/local and make are not recognized despite having Chocolately and MSYS2 installed.
Here is all the material for the MWE:
.tex code:
\documentclass[tikz,convert=pdf2svg]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\angstrom{\text {A}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Etiam lobortis this in inline equation:
\[ \cos(\theta + \phi) = \cos \theta \cos \phi
      - \sin \theta \sin \phi \]
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.
Ut porttitor.
Praesent in sapien.
Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.
Sed interdum libero ut metus.
Pellentesque placerat.
Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris.
Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

\section{Second Section}
This is the second section

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            colorbar,
            colorbar style={
                title=$V$,
                ylabel=\unit{\kilo\cal} \unit{\mol^{-1}},
                ytick={0,50,100,150,200,250},
                xshift=1cm
            },
            xtick={1,2,3,4},xmin=1,xmax=4.5,
            ytick={1,2,3,4},ymin=1,ymax=4.5,
            ztick={0,50,100,150,200,250},zmin=0,zmax=250,
            xlabel={$r_{\mathrm{AB}}\hspace{3px}\left(\unit{\angstrom}\right)$},
            ylabel={$r_{\mathrm{BC}}\hspace{3px}\left(\unit{\angstrom}\right)$},
            zlabel={$V \hspace{3px} \left(\unit{\kilo\cal} \hspace{3px} \unit{\mol^{-1}}\right)$},
            % tick align=outside,
            zticklabel style={yshift=5pt},
            xticklabel style={xshift=5pt},
            x label style={yshift=0.25cm},
            y label style={yshift=0.5cm},
        ]
            \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,domain=1:4.5,y domain=1:4.5] {(128*(1-exp(-(x-1.3)))^2)+(128*(1-exp(-(y-1.3)))^2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sezione dell'ipersuperficie dell'energia potenziale per una generica molecola ABC}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

\blindtext

\end{document}

Lua code:
local system = require 'pandoc.system'

local tikz_doc_template = [[
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\angstrom{\text {A}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[arrow]{hhtensor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\nopagecolor
%s
\end{document}
]]

local function tikz2image(src, filetype, outfile)
  system.with_temporary_directory('tikz2image', function (tmpdir)
    system.with_working_directory(tmpdir, function()
      local f = io.open('tikz.tex', 'w')
      f:write(tikz_doc_template:format(src))
      f:close()
      os.execute('pdflatex tikz.tex')
      if filetype == 'pdf' then
        os.rename('tikz.pdf', outfile)
      elseif filetype == 'png' then
        os.execute("pdftoppm -png tikz.pdf > " .. outfile)
      else
        os.execute('pdf2svg -o' .. outfile .. 'tikz.pdf')
      end
    end)
  end)
end

extension_for = {
  docx = 'png',
  html = 'svg',
  html4 = 'svg',
  html5 = 'svg',
  latex = 'pdf',
  beamer = 'pdf' }

local function file_exists(name)
  local f = io.open(name, 'r')
  if f ~= nil then
    io.close(f)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

local function starts_with(start, str)
  return str:sub(1, #start) == start
end


function RawBlock(el)
  if starts_with('\\begin{tikzpicture}', el.text) then
    local filetype = extension_for[FORMAT] or 'svg'
    local fname = system.get_working_directory() .. '/' ..
        pandoc.sha1(el.text) .. '.' .. filetype
    if not file_exists(fname) then
      tikz2image(el.text, filetype, fname)
    end
    return pandoc.Para({pandoc.Image({}, fname)})
  else
   return el
  end
end

Prompt command: pandoc --from latex+raw_tex --lua-filter=tikz-to-png.lua -s test.tex -o test.odt

Did you consider taking the pandoc-route? (It may provide some other trouble, though, like switching from .tex to markdown manually) Here are some examples, and a link to an online test-environmenr: https://pandoc.org/demos.html

Sorry, I'm new to pandoc. What do you mean with pandoc-route? Am I already using pandoc?

Pandoc claims to convert formats into formats. It may work with, say, many .tex files, but my impression is, the only save way is using markup as a universal source file (which is plain text with some markup-"commands"). I suggest to inspect the online demo which answers most questions by doing. (Try e.g. one Latex example (dropdown box) and convert to markdown) // Unless you or one of your scripts calls pandoc, you probably don't use it so far. // You can also inspect some [pandoc] tags here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandoc

Why are you loading blindtext to create an image? Or at all?

In the odt format you can also add pdf files as images. I'm not sure if the Pandoc Image() constructor also supports that but if it does then you can strip out the svg step completely.
